# Overriding Bootstrap css variables

Tags: css, themes, overriding, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to bring some modifications to the data-bs-theme in Bootstrap 5.3. What I'm trying to do is change the already declared css variables from Boostrap dark theme and bring some changes to the colour pallet. I.E. I want my blue button(btn-primary) to be a different shade of blue when html[data-bs-theme='dark'].

this is what I'm looking at at the moment

```
html[data-bs-theme='dark'] {
    --bs-btn-color: #fff;
    --bs-btn-bg: #ff0000;
    --bs-btn-border-color: #ff0000;
    --bs-btn-hover-color: #fff;
    --bs-btn-hover-bg: #ff0000;
    --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #ff0000;
    --bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb: 49,132,253;
    --bs-btn-active-color: #fff;
    --bs-btn-active-bg: #ff0000;
    --bs-btn-active-border-color: #ff0000;
    --bs-btn-active-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    --bs-btn-disabled-color: #fff;
    --bs-btn-disabled-bg: #ff0000;
    --bs-btn-disabled-border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```
html[data-bs-theme='light'] {
  --bs-btn-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-bg: #0d6efd;
  --bs-btn-border-color: #0d6efd;
  --bs-btn-hover-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-hover-bg: #0b5ed7;
  --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #0a58ca;
  --bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb: 49,132,253;
  --bs-btn-active-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-active-bg: #0a58ca;
  --bs-btn-active-border-color: #0a53be;
  --bs-btn-active-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  --bs-btn-disabled-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-disabled-bg: #0d6efd;
  --bs-btn-disabled-border-color: #0d6efd;
}
```

This is just some exaggerated testing code to try and see if I can get it to pop out red or green.

This is what the css from Bootstrap looks like once the website is loaded

```
.btn-primary
{
  --bs-btn-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-bg: #0d6efd;
  --bs-btn-border-color: #0d6efd;
  --bs-btn-hover-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-hover-bg: #0b5ed7;
  --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #0a58ca;
  --bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb: 49,132,253;
  --bs-btn-active-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-active-bg: #0a58ca;
  --bs-btn-active-border-color: #0a53be;
  --bs-btn-active-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  --bs-btn-disabled-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-disabled-bg: #0d6efd;
  --bs-btn-disabled-border-color: #0d6efd;
}
```

I under stand I could call back the .btn-primary in my css file and override it that way but that seems messy(unless some pro can tell me otherwise).

I'm also not looking to use scss if possible due to the amount of time it would require to setup the whole source file and the deployment size from the hosting and also that this is mostly just a 1-3 pages website.

I'm open to any insight or suggestions on what the best course of action would be in order to keep this nice and tidy

Answer (score 0):

You could add a * selector to make the variables from your theme target elements within the HTML rather than the HTML itself - this way .btn-primary will use the theme vars because they have higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```
html[data-bs-theme='dark']  * { ... }
html[data-bs-theme='light'] * { ... }
```

This will also work for other colors targeting other classes (again mind the specificity)

Note! if you encounter a situation where bootstrap is defining variables on a more specific selector e.g. `.btn-primary.fancy.cool`
you can use [:is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#difference_between_is_and_where) to bump the * selector

```
html[data-bs-theme='light'] :is(*, #heavy) { ... }
```

... but try to avoid this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I kind of understand is not very good practice. I ended up using html[data-bs-theme='dark'] .btn-primary{--bs-btn-bg: #3b89fd;} to overide it. Will surelly be looking at the best way I can setup SASS to work local and use the proper technique

Comment: Just to be clear - I don’t see the first part (adding *) as a problem - the remark was about the :is bump